# Can't run "mongo" command (mongo shell) on Ubuntu after installation

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB. I already read the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#additional-information) and MongoDB Community Edition.
It is working

[image]

but, I tried to run the "mongo" command: It is not working!!

[image]

...So i did:

sudo apt install mongodb-clients

(I saw after that this command uninstalled the mongodb server, which i had to install again)

When it finished, i tried again the "mongo" command. It is not working !!
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 18):

You may want to try "**mongosh**" command.

As specified on [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#begin-using-mongodb) you provided.

> Start a mongosh session on the same host machine as the mongod. You
> can run mongosh without any command-line options to connect to a
> mongod that is running on your localhost with default port 27017.

You need a client in order to interact with mongoDB deployment such as [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) or [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass).

> The MongoDB Shell, mongosh, is a fully functional JavaScript and
> Node.js 16.x REPL environment for interacting with MongoDB
> deployments. You can use the MongoDB Shell to test queries and
> operations directly with your database.

Hope It helps.

Comment: Thank you, as i couldn't find mongo anywhere..

Answer (score 9):

The `mongodb-server` and the `mongodb-clients` debian packages were for MongoDB 3.x, maintained by Ubuntu.

Since MongoDB 4.x, MongoDB provide their own debian packages, but they named them `mongodb-org-server`, `mongodb-mongosh` and `mongodb-cli`. The client command `mongo` is split into two different commands `mongocli` and `mongosh`.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to try "mongosh" command

Comment: Please don't repeat answers