# can't running mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, macos, shell, terminal

I'm trying to run mongo shell after i downloaded it with:

```
___-MacBook-Air bin % sudo cp ./* /usr/local/bin/

mongo
```

i got :

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.15-rc0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I gave permission on my system (I'm using mac)

and used the --dbpath and --logpath :

```
mongod --dbpath /Users/____/Documents/MongoDB/mongodb/data --logpath /Users/____/Documents/MongoDB/mongodb/logs/mongo.log
```

and run:

```
mongod
```

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.747+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.750+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.758+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.758+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.764+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.765+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.766+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.766+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.766+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":91230,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Shaylis-MacBook-Air.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.766+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.15-rc0","gitVersion":"25213a5de37ba8238c2a9d35540afb35e83f7de0","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.766+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.766+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.768+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.768+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1113}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-25T10:17:26.768+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

after that i was running on a new terminal :

```
-MacBook-Air ~ % mongo
```

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.15-rc0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

What i'm doing wrong?

I would love for some help!

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276244/cant-run-mongo-command-mongo-shell-on-ubuntu-after-installation/73277705#73277705

Comment: Maybe mongod chrashed. Try to remove file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` manually.

Comment: Log messages says `"msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":91230,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db"`, so your `mongod --dbpath /Users/____/Documents/MongoDB/mongodb/data` is not used. You tried to start `mongod` multiple times. Clean the logile to get correlated logs